# Libreoffice convert docx to pdf page merge format number

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, docker

1/ I install font microsoft success and libreoffice

2/ My command line run to convert docx to pdf:
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf /code/input_files/temp.docx --outdir output.pdf
but it show page merge format number

3/ My image about output pdf
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1gRE.png

4/ I run libreoffice in terminal in docker, can i fix page format number in libreoffice in command line ?